# Windows store app:What are the .pdb folders

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

In my project folder i see that there is a lot of .pdb folders as shown in the picture below:

[image]

What are these folders? and is there anyway i can remove or hide them?

Comment: Looks suspiciously like Visual Studio's caching debug symbols in your project directory! If these folders contain subfolders with long hexadecimal string names *which* in turn contain .pdb files, safe bet that you could delete them. You will also want to configure the symbol cache location (Tools > Options, Debugging > Symbols, the folder specified under *Cache symbols in this directory*)

Comment: Thanks susmits! that solved it! i created annther folder for those files.